# Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value 403 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, php, android, json

I was following a tutorial to learn about connecting to a database from an android app (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=smVIDycK3-k).I followed all the steps in the tutorial.But at the end i get this error on running the app (Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value 403 of type java.lang.Integer cannot be converted to JSONArray)
MainActivity.java looks like this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fetch= (Button) findViewById(R.id.fetch);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);

    fetch.setOnClickListener(this);
}

class task extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void>
{
private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new         ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
    InputStream is = null ;
    String result = "";
    protected void onPreExecute() {
       progressDialog.setMessage("Fetching data...");
       progressDialog.show();
       progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
    @Override
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
        task.this.cancel(true);
       }
    });
     }
       @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
      String url_select = "http://www.andyapp.byethost4.com/demo.php";

      HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);

          ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        //read content
        is =  httpEntity.getContent();                  

        } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = "";
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
        {
           sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();               

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }

            return null;

        }
    protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

        // ambil data dari Json database
        try {
            JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<Jarray.length();i++)
            {
            JSONObject Jasonobject = null;
            Jasonobject = Jarray.getJSONObject(i);

            //get an output on the screen

            String name = Jasonobject.getString("name");
            String db_detail="";

            if(et.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            db_detail = Jasonobject.getString("detail");
            text.setText(db_detail);
            break;
            }


            }
            this.progressDialog.dismiss();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }
    }
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.fetch : new task().execute();break;
    }

}
```

}

demo.php looks like this

```
<?php
mysql_connect("sql306.byethost4.com","user_name","******") or      die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name");
$sql=mysql_query("select * from demo");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$output[]=$row;
print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

So how do i overcome that error.Many thanks for all your help.

Comment: Check the authorization on your php file, it seems that you are not allowed  to read it !

Answer (score 0):

You should post the json response you receive from the server. But the error message said that you had received the String "403" which means "Forbidden". You are not allowed to access your php script. So in `onPostExceute` the following line fails:

`JSONArray Jarray = new JSONArray(result);`